# Velocity deacceleration working incorrectly

Tags: c#, unity, mathematics, debugging

Basicly, I've tried to code velocity into my game, which works sort of. The deaccelaration works sort of, but not correctly.

The problem is, that the positive values, decreases just fine and dandy to 0. (Up and Right) but if the velocity gets negative (Down and Left) the velocity value do get changed, but just changes instantly instead of using the Lerp.

I've tried anything that I can think of really, and which is why i've come here.

It should be said, that Im using the Unity engine and C# for this.

**Velocity code:**

```
if((velocity.z != 0)) {
        velocity.z = Mathf.Lerp(velocity.z, 0, deaccelerationSpeed);
        if((velocity.z < 0.0001f && velocity.z > 0)) {
            velocity.z = 0; 
        } else if((velocity.z < -0.0001f && velocity.z < 0)) {
            velocity.z = 0; 
        }
}

if((velocity.x != 0)) {
    velocity.x = Mathf.Lerp(velocity.x, 0, deaccelerationSpeed);
    if((velocity.x < 0.0001f && velocity.x > 0)) {
        velocity.x = 0; 
    } else if((velocity.x < -0.0001f && velocity.x < 0)) {
        velocity.x = 0;     
    }
}
```

Comment: Your conditionals don't make any sense and you're snapping velocity to 0 when velocity is less than zero...

Comment: Why are you handling the X and Z properties for your velocity separately?

Comment: I can see what you're attempting to do here, however, I would argue that lerping the different components of your velocity is the wrong way about it.
I'm also thinking your conditionals are a fix of some kind?
Anyway, I would suggest looking up calculating velocity as:
`newVelocity = velocity + deltaTime * acceleration`
Basic physics stuff which will give you much greater control of what's going on.

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in physics Unity has?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, your conditionals don't make any sense. The first will never execute and the 2nd is redundant. In the redundant conditional, you're setting velocity to zero *when velocity is less than zero*. Stew on that for a moment.

```
velocity.x = Mathf.Lerp(velocity.x, 0, deaccelerationSpeed);
if(Mathf.Abs(velocity.x) < 0.0001f) velocity.x = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Drew mentioned, your conditionals don't make any sense for what you're trying to achieve. Instead, try:

```
velocity.z = Mathf.Lerp(velocity.z, 0, deaccelerationSpeed);
if (velocity.z < 0.01f && velocity.z > -0.01f)
    velocity.z = 0.0f;
```

Also, be careful of using the == operator with floats, since floats don't always evaluate they way you expect. If you haven't yet, go to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values) question and read the excellent answer by R...